# Measure flange distance from wall without removing toilet

Tags: plumbing, toilet

I want to install a new toilet. However, I need to get a new one first and I have to know the distance from the wall to the center of the flange. Therein lies the problem. How can I measure this distance without removing the toilet? Do the screw areas of the toilet align with the center of the flange?

I know the standard is usually a foot, however this doesn't quite look like it is that much.

Comment: `Do the screw areas of the toilet align with the center of the flange?` ... yes

Comment: I had an old house with an 11 “ offset , so I cut back  the drywall and studs 2” to recess the wall where the toilet was.

Comment: Yea that won't work here for aesthetic and structure reasons (load bearing)

Answer (score 2):

The important dimension is from the wall to the centerline of the bolts that hold the toilet in place. Measuring from the base is inaccurate. The tightest I have installed a toilet from the wall is 11 1/2" or so, when the toilet was 12" rough in. If you have baseboard that is 3/4" thick, you measurement could be as tight as 10 3/4" from the baseboard.

Comment: Baseboard in this case is about 1/4in tile. From the tile to the bolts it is 11in. That's about 11.25in total to the flange center then. Should be enough for a standard 12" distance toilet right?

Comment: They do make toilets that have a 10" , 12" or 14" rough -in. The 10" and 14" are usually special order.

Comment: Yea I just have to figure out if there will be enough clearance with the top portion to the wall. If not I'll have to go with the 10" as it is indeed special order at hd

Comment: I have had a toilet go into a very tight space as yours, it did work, it leaned the tanks forward a little so the bowl would set proper on the floor, it was a replacement so it was done before. Fortunately my install did not leak either... As a note, the 12" rough in allows typically for a little space to the wall behind the tank. It may depend on the brand of toilet, but I have seen as much as an inch.